# Matching Windows File Directory to JTable

Tags: java, email, pdf, jakarta-mail

I would like to write a java application for work that finds PDF files in a computer directory and searches a JTable to see if that file name is listed in the preset JTable. If the file name does exist in the JTable, then i need to send that PDF file to email address returned from the JTable. The JTable has a two columned structure (Customer Number, Email Address). The PDF Files are named as the customer number so if they exist in the JTable, i need to return the email address and then send it using Java Mail API.

I have this code below working at the moment which matches a file from a specific directory and emails it, but im not sure how i can match files in a windows directory (C:/Program Files) to a JTable with preset values already.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. (I can supply more code if needed)

```
    MainFrame.java

    String[] emails = {"Text1.txt"};

    File folder = new File(txtPDFLocation.getText());
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    boolean isItThere = false;
    for(File file : listOfFiles) {
        if(file.isFile()) {
            if(file.getName().equals(emails[0])) {
                isItThere = true;
            }
            System.out.println(file.getName());
        }
        else if(file.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory " + file.getName());
        }
    }

    if(isItThere) {
        System.out.println("MATCHED");

        //Retreive attachment and send
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        String filename = "G:\\PDFTest\\Text1.txt";
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    }
    else {
        System.out.println("NOT MATCHED");

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you working with Java 1.7+, you could use Javas Non-Blocking I/O classes.
The tutorial from Oracle covers all the basics working with files: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html

Basically you have to create a `java.nio.file.Path` instance which points to the folder you want to search, e.g

```
// Microsoft Windows syntax
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\home\\joe\\foo");

// Solaris syntax
Path path = Paths.get("/home/joe/foo");
```

Note that you always get a `Path` instance, even if the specified path doesn't exist. 
The `Files` class has some static utility methods like `exists()` or `isDirectory()` to verify `Path` objects.

With a valid `Path` object you can process the contents of a directory with a [`FileVisitor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html) or via [`DirectoryStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html).

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Takendarkk I made some additions, do you think it's better now ?